# Subquery In if Statement (plsql)

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to find if **p_param2** is in subquery then do some operations according to this result. This subquery returns more than 1 row.

```
  if p_param1 = 1
     and p_param2 in (select code from x_table where code is not null) then
    --..Some operations..
  end if;
```

But I get *PLS-00405* error. How can write this code effectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the needed value before `IF..THEN` statement within a seperate SQL query, while the current case is not possible. Try such a method which uses `COUNT()` aggregation without need of exception handling :

```
DECLARE
  p_param1 ...
  p_param2 ... 
  p_exists INT;
BEGIN
   SELECT SIGN( COUNT(*) )
     INTO p_exists
     FROM x_table 
    WHERE code IS NOT NULL 
      AND code = p_param2;
      
 IF p_param1 = 1 AND p_exists = 1 THEN
   -- some operations
 END IF;
END; 
/
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare a var `v_dummy number`. Then:

```
begin
   select 1
     into v_dummy
     from x_table
    where code = p_param2;

   exception
      when no_data_found then
         v_dummy := 0;
end;

if p_param1 = 1 and v_dummy = 1 then
.
.
.
end if;
```

If x_table.code can contain duplicate values, you have to decide what to do when more than one occurrence of p_param2 is found.

Comment: this case fails whenever `code` matches `p_param2` for more than one records.

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to say in my last sentence. If you want to ignore multiple records, just add `and rownum=1` to the select statement. Otherwise please explain what should happen in that case.

Comment: you might add `when too_many_rows then v_dummy := 1;` also.